Is there a solution to the Indexing bug in macOS 15.1
Since I and others have upgraded to macOS 15.1, the indexing of the Macintosh HD never ends. Every time I launch Spotlight, below it I see "Indexing" and a progress bar that never gets past the 25% mark. There have been suggestions to use Terminal to shut off indexing until the the next incremental update, and I have done so but I never realized how much I uses Spotlight until turning it off.

If there is a bug, it doesn't affect everyone. Have you tried rebuilding the index? https://support.apple.com/en-us/102321

In addition to @LincDavis comment, you can also use Terminal to reindex the entire hard drive or select directories, using the mdutil command. For example, sudo mdutil -E / will reindex every internal drive, any mounted disk image, external drives, etc., or you can use sudo mdutil -E /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/ to just reindex Macintosh HD. I'd recommend you read more on the command before you commit to anything. You might also need to delete existing Spotlight cache before reindexing to remove any corrupt cache that's causing the indexing issue...

Note also, each time a file changes, it is recorded by FSEvents database that will trigger Spotlight to reindex the directory/file as long as that directory is in Spotlight's watchlist of directories. You can choose which directories are in Spotlight's watchilst by going to Spotlight's privacy settings in system settings. Furthermore, spotlight typically reindexes some directories on each reboot of your Mac to clear up any old log/cache files that have changed/removed after the reboot, which is why Spotlight is always slow after each reboot and requires some time to reindex

When is a bug formally a bug.  I saw that every time I used Spotlight, below it was the scroll bar indicating it was Indexing and that scroll bar never got beyond roughly the 1/3 mark. That sent me looking on several sites where I found lots of folks were having this problem.  Some gave up and turned off Indexing in the hope that the next macOS update would fix it.  I have never seen this Indexing behavior before & I have had Macs since 1995.  This is not normal.

Turn Spotlight indexing off:
sudo mdutil -i off /
Remove Spotlight indexes:
sudo mdutil -E /
Turn Spotlight indexing on:
sudo mdutil -i on /
Then did this


Open Terminal:

Click on the Spotlight search icon (magnifying glass) in the top-right corner of your screen.
Type "Terminal" and press Enter to open the Terminal application.



Check indexing status:


In the Terminal window, type the following command and press Enter:
sudo mdutil -s /
Did the above, let's see what happens now.





Reporting back to close the loop and advise that the actions enumerated in my last post did the trick.  When I launch Spotlight and initiate a search, the Indexing scroll bar is no longer there.
